# Make Gojs FlowCart working on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, gojs

For my current project, I'm using this amazing library ["GoJS"](http://gojs.net/latest/index.html), that offers many awesome diagrams.

The problem is that the library is based on Javascript, and does not have any AngularJS wrapper.
The only angular code I found, is the based diagram http://gojs.net/latest/samples/angular.html

For my project, I need to use FlowChart http://gojs.net/latest/samples/flowchart.html.

I've tried to wrap it into a directive, but without any luck.

So, that's way I'm asking your help today, to provide me with a solution to easily integrate the diagram into my angulaJS app, or provide me with any wrapper that can work without any issue.

Thanks

Comment: juz a marker, even I am looking towards, the same for a sample to learn.. Is it possible.. I am starting..

Comment: Did you find a way to implement it? If yes, please post your solution!

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the [GoJS Angular Component](https://github.com/NorthwoodsSoftware/gojs-angular). The [gojs-angular-basic](https://github.com/NorthwoodsSoftware/gojs-angular-basic) project is an example using it.